# Why is this error coming up "No resource identifer found for attiribute values in android?

Tags: java, android

in the Java code ... the "R" is highlighted ... message "Cannot resolve R"

```
public class HomePage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        TextView intro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        Button aboutBtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutBtn);
```

Then when I try to build: 
**I get the following errors:**

```
C:\Users\Ptrykiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Business_App\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(46) No resource identifier found for attribute 'values' in package 'android'
Error:(46) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-L\android.jar -M C:\Users\Ptrykiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Business_App\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Ptrykiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Business_App\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\Ptrykiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Business_App\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\Ptrykiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Business_App\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\Ptrykiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Business_App\app\build\intermediates\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.ptr.ptrykiel.business_app -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Ptrykiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Business_App\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    C:\Users\Ptrykiel\AndroidStudioProjects\Business_App\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:46: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'values' in package 'android'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the AndroidManifest at line 46

Comment: Just clean your project and make sure build automatically is checked, if you have any error in your xml file R.java will not be generated hence resolve xml error and then clean your project

Comment: check your import , maybe you import android.R instead of yourPackage.R

Comment: i figured it out ... I had two typos in the manifest.xml

Comment: Post Your XML of layout and AndroidManifest

Comment: thanks for all of your help ... figured out I had two typos. Now I have to update Google Play services ... not sure what that is all about